# js file doesn't import a js module correctly, even with type="module" inserted on the html

Tags: javascript, html, object, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have a js class inside movie.js that I'd like to import to my code on main.js where I plan to work with it.
I've been struggling with the following error: 
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

I have already put the type="module" tag in the HTML and checked if the import/export are in the right place. I saw another answers to similar questions, but none solved the case.

(This is the relevant HTML)

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src='main.js' async></script>
  <script src='movie.js' type="module" ></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <a class="btn">Search</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

```
import Movie from './movie.js';

const btnSearch = document.querySelector(".btn");


btnSearch.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let filmeTeste = new Movie("The Lego Movie", 2014, "tt1490017", "Movie", "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg4MDk1ODExN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzIyNjg3MDE@._V1_SX300.jpg");
    console.log(`object test ${filmeTeste}`);
});
```

```
class Movie {
    constructor(title, year, imdbID, type, poster){
        this.title = title;
        this.year = year;
        this.imdbID = imdbID;
        this.type = type;
        this.poster = poster;
    };
}
export default Movie;
```

I expect to get the object printed in the console, but right now it only shows me SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module main.js:1

Comment: [Scripts that import modules must also be declared modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#Applying_the_module_to_your_HTML)

Comment: @jro It worked! Thank you very very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add the `type="module"` to your other `<script>` tag, because it also uses modules.

```
<script src="main.js" async type="module"></script>
<script src="movie.js" type="module" ></script>
```

Comment: The `<script src="movie.js" type="module" ></script>` also shouldn't be needed in the first place, since `main.js` already imports/loads it.

Comment: Yes @loganfsmyth, that's true.